# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I really dont understand where is the mistake. I have a database named giderler. And it includes id(Primary key),kisi (varchar), tur (varchar), fiyat (varchar), mal(varchar), tarih (datetime), hesap (int). And I just want to add some records to table. I'm looking for an one hour on the internet, but i cant find anything, any answer.

Here is the codes:

```
if(isset($_POST['AddExpense'])){

    /* Formdan gerekli veiler alınıyor */
    $kisi = $_POST['kisi'];
    $tur = $_POST['tur'];
    $fiyat = $_POST['fiyat'];
    $mal = $_POST['mal'];

    if(!is_numeric($fiyat))
    {
        /* Fiyat sadece integer değer alıyor. */
        echo '<div id="error">Lütfen Fiyatı Sadece Rakam Olarak Giriniz!</div>';
        die;
        }

    $tarih = date("d-m-Y 00:00:00");        /* Tarih formatı gg-aa-yy */
    echo $kisi. ' - ' .$tur. ' - ' .$mal. ' - ' .$fiyat. ' - '. $tarih;
    /* Veritabanına kayıt gerçekleştiriliyor */
    try{
    $add_expense = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO giderler (kisi,tur,mal,fiyat,tarih,hesap) VALUES (:kisi,:tur,:mal,:fiyat,:tarih,:hesap");
    $add_expense->execute(array(
        ':kisi' => $kisi,
        ':tur' => $tur,
        ':mal' => $mal,
        ':fiyat' => $fiyat,
        ':tarih' => $tarih,
        ':hesap' => 0 /* Yeni girilen kayıt. Ödeşmeler gerçekleşmedi. Bu değer ay sonunda 1 olacak */
        ));

    echo '<div id="successs">Sayın '.$kisi.', Kaydınız Başarıyla Eklendi.</div>';

    /*Exception fırlatılıyor*/
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo 'Error: '.$ex->getMessage();
        }   
    }
```

Here is the exception:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line
>   1

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `)` at the end

```
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO giderler (kisi,tur,mal,fiyat,tarih,hesap) 
              VALUES (:kisi,:tur,:mal,:fiyat,:tarih,:hesap");
                                                          ^-------here
```

Comment: ohh, thanks bro :) these kind of forgetfulness make me crazy :)